# Processors are not working in Apache NiFi if 'Execution: Primary node' is selected

Tags: apache-nifi

All processors in my jobs are using only primary node ('Execution: Primary node' setting for a processor). But sometimes components stop running until I change this setting to 'Execution: All nodes'.
I can see in Cluster menu that primary cluster is connected and column 'Last Heartbeated' equals current datetime.

Does anyone know why this behaviour appears? And how to continue using only primary node or what else I need to check regarding primary node functionality?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Is this happening only with specific processors? What is the high-level logic behind the flow?

Comment: Actually this issue happens for quite different processors, e.g. ExecuteSQL, MergeContent, etc. It happens not too often and then disappears but it is really annoying.
The overall logic is data migration from one system to another. 
I thought that maybe this thing happens because of some general issues with cluster?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue for multiple nifi processors when running in Primary Only mode.   Has anyone corrected this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In InFile --> OutFile processor, It does not allow single node in Out-settings, so, put up for multi node, it works fine..